# How does one set app:insetForeground programmatically for DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, drawerlayout

Looking at the blog [here](http://matthewwear.xyz/no-excuses-it-takes-5-mins-make-that-drawer-visible-under-your-status-bar-2/) to describe how to use `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`. I'd like to be able to set `app:insetForeground` programmatically. How does one go about doing that?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="@color/inset_color"
    >
```

Comment: Won't `drawerLayout.setScrimColor()` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The article you link to mentions this method to set the scrim collor programmatically:

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transp_red));
```